# After installing sysstat on an AWS EC2 instance: kernel: ena: Feature 27 isn't supported

Tags: linux, debian, amazon-ec2, syslog, sar

After installing and enabling `sysstat` on an AWS EC2 instance I get the following log entries everytime `sysstat` is run (from the cronjob in `/etc/cron.d/sysstat`) in my `/var/log/syslog` file on Debian:

```
kernel: [95827.487657] ena: Feature 27 isn't supported
```

Does anyone know what this means? Is it important or can it be ignored? How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting-ena.html) for the Elastic Network Adapter states:

> ### Which errors can I ignore?
>
> #### Feature X isn't supported
>
> 27: The Elastic Network Adapter driver does not support polling the Ethernet capabilities from snmpd.